# Fitting a Keras model with large amount of data using a custom data generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to fit my Keras model with quite large amount of data.

To do this, I'm using custom data generators and `model.fit_generator` function.

However, I can't seem to understand if I'm doing this correctly.

Here's what I have:

```
from os.path import join

import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau

# The function returns a list of image names from folder
from data.preprocessing import get_list_of_images


class VGG19(object):
    def __init__(self, weights_path=None, train_folder='data/train', validation_folder='data/val'):
        self.weights_path = weights_path
        self.model = self._init_model()

        if weights_path:
            self.model.load_weights(weights_path)
        else:
            self.datagen = self._init_datagen()
            self.train_folder = train_folder
            self.validation_folder = validation_folder
            self.model.compile(
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy']
            )

    def fit(self, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10):
        self.model.fit_generator(
            self._generate_data_from_folder(self.train_folder), 32,
            nb_epoch,
            verbose=1,
            callbacks=[
                TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', write_images=True),
                ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5', monitor='val_loss'),
                ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=5, min_lr=0.001)
            ],
            validation_data=self._generate_data_from_folder(self.validation_folder),
            nb_val_samples=32
        )

    def predict(self, X, batch_size=32, verbose=1):
        return self.model.predict(X, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

    def predict_proba(self, X, batch_size=32, verbose=1):
        return self.model.predict_proba(X, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

    def _init_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        # model definition goes here...
        return model

    def _init_datagen(self):
        return ImageDataGenerator(
            featurewise_center=True,
            samplewise_center=False,
            featurewise_std_normalization=True,
            samplewise_std_normalization=False,
            zca_whitening=False,
            rotation_range=20,
            width_shift_range=0.2,
            height_shift_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True,
            vertical_flip=True
        )

    def _generate_data_from_folder(self, folder_path):
        while 1:
            images = get_list_of_images(folder_path)

            for image_path in images:
                x = cv2.imread(join(folder_path, image_path))
                y = 0 if image_path.split('.')[0] == 'dog' else 1

                yield (x, y)
```

---

My dataset consists of images with names like:

- `cat.[number].jpg`, i.e.: `cat.124.jpg`
- `dog.[number].jpg`, i.e.: `dog.64.jpg`

So, basically, I'm trying to train a model to perform a binary cat-dog classification.

---

Is my `_generate_data_from_folder` function correctly implemented for mini-batch optimization?

How can I add the usage of `ImageDataGenerator` to my `_generate_data_from_folder` function (from the `_init_datagen` function)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'add the usage'?

Comment: @nemo I mean I'd like to add data augmentation using `ImageDataGenerator`, however, I'm not sure how to do this. Should I put `ImageDataGenerator.flow()` generator inside my other generator or use it somehow differently? And I'm not sure if my data generator function is correct as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's the github link to my final version of the project that I got working:

https://github.com/yakovenkodenis/dogs-vs-cats-kaggle

Hope, it helps somebody